# Access image source based on change

Tags: javascript

I have a function which I call to change the image src.

```
function checkImage(imageSrc, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc;
    img.onload = function() {
        var loadImage = imageSrc.replace("_1.jpg", "_2.jpg");
        callback(loadImage);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {};
 }
```

Example of how it gets called:

```
var imageSrc = 'http://www.test.com/test_1.jpg';
if(imageSrc.indexOf('_1.jpg') {
  checkImage(imageSrc, function(result) {console.log(result);})
}
```

So basically the above calls the function checkImage if the imageSrc contains '_1' I get the correct image path back but I cannot figure out how to set imageSrc to be the new path. I have tried below but I just get the original value.
    checkImage(imageSrc, function(result) {imageSrc = result;});

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I know you want to check image src. What shoult happen if image src contain `_1.jpg`?

Comment: So when you do `checkImage(imageSrc, function(result) { imageSrc = result; console.log(imageSrc); });` it doesn't show the correct result? It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/38w3asc4/) (moved the callback outside onload as there isn't an image at that URL to load)

Comment: You need to use `replace` only. See https://jsfiddle.net/38w3asc4/1/